# Symfony Doctrine DQL cannot find createQuery in entity manager

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, doctrine-query

I've been learning web development with Symfony for some time now.
I was following the tutorial on Symfony's [website](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) and [Doctrine tutorial](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), and tried to use entity manager in the Doctrine ORM to create queries but PhpStorm's autocompletion tells me that it couldn't find `createquery()`. (see below for screenshot)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you learning good practices for Symfony, you have to get repository before create the query

Comment: You don't need to get the repo first.  It's common but not required.  The repo just passes the call up to the entity manager anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your screenshot *(getRepository, flush, persist...)* are methods of **$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()**, that you can found on any symfony **controller** class :

[image]

What you want to use is **$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery()** that you can found on symfony **repository** class :

[image]

So the proper way doing this is to create a Repository and add your method into it, then use this method inside your controller :

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{

  /**
   * @Route("/", name="user_list")
   */
  public function indexAction()
  {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $userrs = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->myRepositoryMethod();
      ...
```

Comment: Oh cheers, this is working now. So this means that I only define queries in **repository** right?

Comment: Yes better place for custom queries is Repository.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have included the following use statement

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
```

Comment: Please replace 'use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager'
with 'use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager', then you will be able to find method createQuery()